# Build and save with associations

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to build a user, create a location (I'm using google geocode API) and save all, but the association isn't created in the database. Everything is working fine. The response is exactly what I want but when I go into the database, the association isn't created. The only way I made it work was to create and save the location entity separately and directly set the foreign key "locationId" to the newly generated ID. It's been almost a week and I still can't figure out how to make it work. If it can help, I'm also using PostgreSQL. Here is the doc for [creation with associations.](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#creating-with-associations)

Here are my associations:

```
User.belongsTo(models.Location, { as: 'location', foreignKey: 'locationId' });
Location.hasMany(models.User, { as: 'users', foreignKey: 'locationId' });
```

Here is my controller code:

```
const createRandomToken = crypto
  .randomBytesAsync(16)
  .then(buf => buf.toString('hex'));

const createUser = token => User.build({
  firstName: req.body.firstName,
  lastName: req.body.lastName,
  email: req.body.email,
  passwordResetToken: token,
  passwordResetExpires: moment().add(1, 'days'),
  role: req.body.roleId,
  active: true
}, {
  include: [{ model: Location, as: 'location' }]
});

const createLocation = (user) => {
  if (!user) return;
  if (!req.body.placeId) return user;
  return googleMapsHelper.getLocationByPlaceId(req.body.placeId).then((location) => {
    user.location = location;
    return user;
  });
};

const saveUser = (user) => {
  if (!user) return;
  return user.save()
    .then(user => res.json(user.getPublicInfo()));
};

createRandomToken
  .then(createUser)
  .then(createLocation)
  .then(saveUser)
  .catch(Sequelize.ValidationError, (err) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < err.errors.length; i++) {
      if (err.errors[i].type === 'unique violation') {
        return next(createError.Conflict(err.errors[i]));
      }
    }
  })
  .catch(err => next(createError.InternalServerError(err)));
```

Here's the response:

```
{
  "id": 18,
  "firstName": "FirstName",
  "lastName": "LastName",
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "lastLogin": null,
  "passwordResetExpires": "2018-04-15T21:02:34.624Z",
  "location": {
    "id": 5,
    "placeId": "ChIJs0-pQ_FzhlQRi_OBm-qWkbs",
    "streetNumber": null,
    "route": null,
    "city": "Vancouver",
    "postalCode": null,
    "country": "Canada",
    "region": "British Columbia",
    "formatted": "Vancouver, BC, Canada",
    "createdAt": "2018-04-14T20:57:54.196Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-04-14T20:57:54.196Z"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple back and forth with sequelize Github, I achieved to do the same thing using a transaction, the setters and modifying my promise logic.

```
const createLocation = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if (!req.body.placeId) return resolve();
  googleMapsHelper
    .getLocationByPlaceId(req.body.placeId)
    .then(location => resolve(location))
    .catch(() => reject(createError.BadRequest('PlaceId invalide')));
});

const createUser = () => sequelize.transaction((t) => {
  const user = User.build({
    firstName: req.body.firstName,
    lastName: req.body.lastName,
    email: req.body.email,
    passwordResetToken: crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex'),
    passwordResetExpires: moment().add(1, 'days'),
    active: true
  });
  return user.save({ transaction: t })
    .then(user => createLocation
      .then(location => user.setLocation(location, { transaction: t })));
});

createUser
  .then(user => res.json(user))
  .catch(err => httpErrorHandler(err, next));
```